# Doubt in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In one point of a proof (which is irrelevant in this context), it is mentioned that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then $\operatorname{range} (T-\lambda I) \ni \lambda u$ where $u$ is the corresponding eigenvector.

I can't see how this is true. I thought to apply this transform ($T-\lambda I$) on scalar multiples of $u$ but they don't work.

Comment: What is $u$ here?

Comment: The corresponding eigenvect

Comment: I think the theorem they're proving might be actually relevant.

Comment: This is not true. Consider $T = I$, $\lambda = 1$, and $u$ any nonzero vector. Are you sure you have stated the problem correctly? What is true is that $u$ (and hence any scalar multiple of $u$, including $\lambda u$) is in the null space of $T - \lambda I$.

Comment: It was used in the proof that given a complex vector space, and a linear operator T in $\mathcal{L}(V)$, there is a basis of $V$ wrt which the matrix of $T$ wrt the basis is upper diagonal

Comment: If this is from a book, please also list the author, title, and page/theorem number.

Comment: Sheldon axler, linear algebra done right, page 84

Comment: In my copy (3rd ed.) it's page 149 (theorem 5.27): "Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional complex vector space and $T \in \mathcal L(V)$. Then $T$ has an upper-triangular matrix with respect to some basis of $V$." Nowhere in the proof does he say that $u$ is an eigenvector of $T$. What he says is that (after defining $U = \operatorname{range}(T - \lambda I)$): "suppose $u \in U$" ... "obviously $(T - \lambda I)u \in U$ (because $U$ equals the range of $T - \lambda I$) and $\lambda u \in U$..." Does your copy say something different?

Comment: I guess the opposite might be true, $\lambda u\notin\operatorname{range} (T-\lambda I)$

Answer (score 2):

If $u$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, by definition $Tu  =\lambda u$ (and $u \neq 0$). $\lambda u = (\lambda I) u$, where $I$ is the identity operator. So $$(T-\lambda I)(u) = Tu - (\lambda I)(u) = Tu  -\lambda u =0$$

and so $$u \in \text{null}(T-\lambda I)$$ where null (or ker) is the null space of an operator. It's *not* in general in the range of $T - \lambda I$: a trivial counterexample is to take $T=\lambda I$ itself. So I think your text has a mistake. It shoudl say null space, (or kernel), not range.

Comment: See my comment above; I looked at my copy of the book the OP is referring to (Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*). The proof doesn't say what the OP says it says. In particular, $u$ is meant to be an arbitrary element of $\operatorname{range}(T - \lambda I)$. It is *not* an eigenvector of $T$. Agree of course with your answer which addresses the question as written. (+1)